# How to make plotting possible on x-axis lines only? (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, plot

I've just started with trying out the d3 library.

I am trying to create an interactive line chart where people can plot their own points. You can find it over here: http://jsfiddle.net/6FjJ2/

My question is: **how can I make sure that plotting can only be done on the x-axis' lines?** *If you check out my example, you will see it kind of works,* but with a lot of cheating. Check out the **ok** variable... What would be the correct way of achieving this? I have no idea how I can achieve this with a ... so I'm getting a lot of seperate 's.

```
   var data = [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5],
   w      = 1000,
   h      = 300,

   monthsData = [],
   months     = 18;

   for(i = 0; i < months; i++) {
     monthsData.push(i);
   }

   var max = d3.max(monthsData),
   x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, monthsData.length]).range([0, w]),
   y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, max]).range([h, 0]),

   pointpos = [];

   lvl  = [0, 10],
   lvly = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(lvl)]).range([h, 0]);

   svg = d3.select(".chart")
           .attr("width", w)
           .attr("height", h);

   svg.selectAll('path.line')
   // Return "data" array which will form the path coordinates
      .data([data])
   // Add path
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
                       .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
                       .y(y));

   // Y-axis ticks
   ticks = svg.selectAll(".ticky")
   // Change number of ticks for more gridlines!
              .data(lvly.ticks(10))
                        .enter().append("svg:g")
                        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0, " +  (lvly(d)) + ")"; })
                        .attr("class", "ticky");

   ticks.append("svg:line")
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", 0)
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("x2", w);

   ticks.append("svg:text")
        .text( function(d) { return d; })
        .attr("text-anchor","end")
        .attr("dy", 2)
        .attr("dx", -4);

   // X-axis ticks
   ticks = svg.selectAll(".tickx")
              .data(x.ticks(monthsData.length))
                                      .enter().append("svg:g")
                                      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" +  (x(i)) + ", 0)"; })
                                      .attr("class", "tickx");

   ticks.append("svg:line")
        .attr("y1", h)
        .attr("y2", 0)
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("x2", 0);

   ticks.append("svg:text")
        .text( function(d, i) { return i; })
        .attr("y", h)
        .attr("dy", 15)
        .attr("dx", -2);

   //   var d = $(".tickx:first line").css({"stroke-width" : "2", opacity : "1"});

   var line;
   var ok = -55;

   svg.on("mousedown", mouseDown)
      .on("mouseup", mouseUp);

   function mouseDown() {
     var m = d3.mouse(this);
     line = svg.append("line")
               .data(monthsData)
     /* .attr("x1", m[0]) */
               .attr("x1", function(d, i) { pointpos.push(m[0]); ok += 55; return ok;})
               .attr("y1", m[1])
               .attr("x2", function(d, i) { return ok + 56; })
     /* .attr("x2", function(d, i) {return 300; }) */
               .attr("y2", m[1]);

     svg.on("mousemove", mouseMove);

     var m = d3.mouse(this);
     var point = svg.append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return ok; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return m[1]; })
                    .attr("r", 8);

     lvl.push(100);
   }

   function mouseMove() {
     var m = d3.mouse(this);
     line.attr("y2", m[1]);
     /* .attr("y1", m[0]); */
   }

   function mouseUp() {
     // Change null to mousemove for a graph kinda draw mode
     svg.on("mousemove", mouseMove);
   }
```

**Excuse my bad code!**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you need a mix of [histogram layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Histogram-Layout#wiki-histogram) and [ordinal scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales). Also, I am pretty sure [d3.svg.axis](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-axis) can draw the axis for you.

Comment: It looks to me as if the example already restricts where new points can be created?

Comment: **@musically_ut**: Thanks, I'll check it out. Did not read that part of the manual yet. Appreciate it._

**Lars**: Yeah that is just the fake cheating way of doing it. If I'd change the width of the svg canvas it would break right away because I am using a static number. I want it to make it calculate. Try it again and you'll see that after plotting a few points, it stops aligning.

Comment: @musically_ut: I solved it. Thanks to your advice. Can't you make it an answer so I can give you some nice points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need:

1. [histogram layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Histogram-Layout#wiki-histogram) for binning your points.
2. [ordinal scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) for restricting their `x-axis` positions according to the bin

As a sidenote, you can use [d3.svg.axis](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-axis) to draw the axis for you.